# What is the easiest way to use Harvard referencing?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, authoryear

I hope you can help me with this issue. I'm new to Latex, so I may miss sth. obvious. So far, I couldn't figure out how to easily implement a bibliography and use the harvard referencing style. I describe my attempt below but something like a step-by-step manual (for beginners) would be very helpful.

I've tried biblatex with style=authoryear but it doesn't seem to read my .bib file. It doesn't suggest the corresponding codes of my references. It also doesn't produce a good in text citation. It merely shows the code I plugged in there from my bibliography. The .bib file is in the same folder as my document. The references in my .bib file are in bibtex format. I've read that bibtex and biblatex formats are compatible.

If someone could help me fix that, that'd be great. I'd simply like an easy-to-use Harvard referencing method for my paper.

Reference example:

```
@article{10.1257/mac.20170388,
Author = {Hsieh, Chang-Tai and Moretti, Enrico},
Title = {Housing Constraints and Spatial Misallocation},
Journal = {American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics},
Volume = {11},
Number = {2},
Year = {2019},
Month = {April},
Pages = {1-39},
DOI = {10.1257/mac.20170388},
URL = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/mac.20170388}}
```

My code:

```
\documentclass[]

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

test citation \cite{}
%Here, it doesn't suggest to me my citations. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `\documentclass[]` cannot possibly be right. Please inform us which document class you employ. Also, your test document is missing a `\printbibliography` statement, you should change `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` to `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`, and the `\cite` instruction must take a non-empty argument. Please fix.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments and suggestions:

- `\documentclass[]` cannot possibly go well. The command *requires* an argument enclosed in curly braces.
- The command  `\cite{}` *must* generate an error message. `\cite` and friends require the argument to be non.empty.
- You should change `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` to `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`.
- You won't get a typeset bibliography unless you provide a `\printbibliography` statement.
- If you want to use the `\citet` and `\citep` directives, made popular by the `natbib` citation management package, all you need to do is specify the option `natbib` while loading `biblatex`.
- Note that there isn't a unique "Harvard" citation style. The option `style=authoryear` chooses but one of many possible implementations of "harvard" style.
- You should look into making the entries' keys in your bib file a bit more mnemonic than `10.1257/mac.20170388`. Just because some database program has been told to use this key does not mean that *you* have to accept the keys' naming conventions. For instance, consider renaming the key to `hsieh-moretti:2019`.
- Last but not least, I would like to suggest that you load the `xurl` package , in order to facilitate the clean typesetting of long URL strings that need to be line-broken.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Create a test bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@article{hsieh-moretti:2019,
    author  = {Hsieh, Chang-Tai and Moretti, Enrico},
    title   = {Housing Constraints and Spatial Misallocation},
    journal = {American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics},
    volume  = {11},
    number  = {2},
    year    = {2019},
    month   = apr,
    pages   = {1--39},
    doi     = {10.1257/mac.20170388},
    url     = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/mac.20170388}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib]{biblatex} % 'backend=biber' is the default
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % handle line breaks in long URL strings gracefully
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citet{hsieh-moretti:2019}, \citep{hsieh-moretti:2019}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the warm TeX.Se welcome! 

I've tried your code (copy-pasted) and I don't get the same result. The PDF just turns out to be "hsieh-moretti:2019, (hsieh-moretti:2019)". No Reference section nor these neat in-text citations. 

When I look at my code, I notice that the command \addbibresource{bib.bib} is printed in yellow (the whole command including the brackets {} ) as supposed to blue for "normal" commands.

Do you have an idea what could be going on?

I use texmaker. General Question(Q): how do I answer to such posts? should I answer my Q or comment or edit my Q?

Comment: @Izz - Your description makes it sound like you haven't run biber inbetween the LaTeX runs. Please confirm whether or not you've actually run biber. Which TeX distribution -- MikTeX? TeXlive? something else? -- do you use? (FWIW, I use MacTeX2021.) I'm afraid I've never used TeXmaker, so I can't help with texmaker issues.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I didn't know that you have to run a different TeX distribution (or indeed what TeX distributions were). I solved it by doing two things:

1. Via preferences -> commands (using macOS) I changed the bib(la)tex command to " biber % ". Originally it was some bibtex command. I haven't checked if it would have worked with the original command but I'm fairly certain it wouldn't.
2. Via preferences -> quick build I changed the automatic quick build to " PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLateX (x2) + View Pdf "

I'm not sure why this new quickbuild runs PdfLaTeX three times but the issue is solved.

Also then using @Mico's tips on linking references and making URLs look nice, I got what I wanted.

Thx.